# Подскажите бесплатный DataGrid WinForms C# с сортировкой, отключением колонок, перемещением колонок

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите DataGrid для WinForms проекта с возможностью сортировки при нажатии на заголовок колонке, отключением/включением колонок (галочка на заголовке колонки), перемена местами колонок.

Может кто-то сам делала такой grid, или есть опыт использования стороннего?

Comment: А что разве стандартный `DataGrid` не умеет сортировать и в нем нельзя перемещать колонки?

Comment: да умеет, извиняюсь что это тоже добавил, давно не пользовался WinForms. остается только отключение колонок.

Comment: Что значит отключение, выбрал колонку и нажал на кнопку скрыть и она перестала отображаться в `DataGrid `?

Comment: да по сути воздействие на Visible колонки. Но получается если колонка исчезла при первом нажатии то как ее отобразить потом. Нужно выпадающее меню при клике правой кнопкой мыши на колонку, в котором и выставляются флаги Visible

Comment: Застряли то вы  на чем, что конкретно не понятно как сделать. Как сделать контекстное меню или как отобразить список колонок?

Answer (score 0):

В простом варианте можно сделать так. Я исхожу из того, что у вас уже создан элемент `ContextMenuStrip`, который связан с нужным `DataGridView`.

1) Создаем метод, который будет инициализировать список элементов в `ContextMenuStrip` именами колонок из `DataGridView`.

```
private void InitContextMenuStrip()
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in contextMenuStrip.Items)
    {
        item.Click -= MenuItemOnClick;
    }

    contextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in mainDataGridView.Columns)
    {
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem()
        {
            Checked = column.Visible,
            Text = column.Name
        };

        item.Click += MenuItemOnClick;
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

2) В обработчике нажатия на пункт меню получаем элемент, по которому кликнули и отображаем нужную колонку.

```
private void MenuItemOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var target = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

    // Сбрасываем флаг на противоположный.
    target.Checked = !target.Checked;

    // Скрываем/показываем колонку.
    mainDataGridView.Columns[target.Text].Visible = target.Checked;
}
```

3) Метод сокрытия колонки:

```
private void HideColumnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mainDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        // Получаем колонку и скрываем ее.
        var index = mainDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
        mainDataGridView.Columns[index].Visible = false;

        InitContextMenuStrip();
    }
}
```